# Robocopy batch with wildcards copies more files than it should. Why?

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy, xcopy, robocopy

This is my first question her, so please be patient with me :)

I have several folders full of 10,000+ files for daily datasets in the form of 19810101.dbf for the first of January 1981 and so on. I want do robocopy these per year to a folder using a batch file and wildcards. It looks like this:

robocopy d:\files d:\results\1981 1981*.dbf

robocopy d:\files d:\results\1982 1982*.dbf

etc.

The copy works, BUT it copies more files than it should. These include filenames like 19970625.dbf where is no 1981 in sight.

So what I'm I doing wrong here? Is it a bug? I also tried copy and xcopy with the same results. I's really frustrating by now. Can someone please show me the way?

Thank you!

---

Here is the output of robocopy. There are 20 more files than there should be, from the years 1982 to 1997.

```
D:\>robocopy d:\files d:\results\1981 1981*.dbf

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robustes Dateikopieren für Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Gestartet: Thu Nov 27 13:04:01 2014

   Quelle : d:\files\
     Ziel : d:\results\1981\

    Dateien : 1981*.dbf

  Optionen: /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                         385    d:\files\
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810101_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810102_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810103_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810104_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810105_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810106_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810107_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810108_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810109_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810110_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810111_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810112_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810113_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810114_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810115_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810116_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810117_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810118_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810119_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810120_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810121_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810122_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810123_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810124_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810125_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810126_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810127_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810128_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810129_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810130_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810131_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810201_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810202_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810203_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810204_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810205_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810206_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810207_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810208_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810209_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810210_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810211_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810212_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810213_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810214_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810215_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810216_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810217_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810218_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810219_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810220_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810221_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810222_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810223_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810224_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810225_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810226_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810227_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810228_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810301_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810302_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810303_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810304_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810305_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810306_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810307_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810308_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810309_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810310_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810311_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810312_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810313_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810314_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810315_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810316_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810317_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810318_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810319_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810320_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810321_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810322_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810323_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810324_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810325_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810326_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810327_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810328_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810329_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810330_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810331_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810401_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810402_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810403_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810404_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810405_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810406_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810407_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810408_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810409_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810410_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810411_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810412_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810413_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810414_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810415_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810416_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810417_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810418_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810419_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810420_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810421_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810422_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810423_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19810424_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810425_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810426_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810427_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810428_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810429_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810430_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810501_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810502_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810503_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810504_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810505_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810506_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810507_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810508_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810509_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810510_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810511_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810512_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810513_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810514_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810515_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810516_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810517_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810518_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810519_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810520_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810521_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810522_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810523_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810524_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810525_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810526_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810527_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810528_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810529_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810530_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810531_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810601_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810602_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810603_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810604_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810605_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810606_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810607_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810608_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810609_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810610_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810611_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810612_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810613_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810614_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810615_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810616_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810617_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810618_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810619_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810620_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810621_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810622_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810623_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810624_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810625_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810626_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810627_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810628_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810629_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810630_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810701_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810702_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810703_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810704_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810705_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810706_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810707_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810708_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810709_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810710_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810711_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810712_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810713_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810714_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810715_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810716_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810717_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810718_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810719_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810720_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810721_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810722_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810723_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810724_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810725_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810726_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810727_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810728_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810729_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810730_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810731_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810801_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810802_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810803_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810804_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810805_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810806_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810807_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810808_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810809_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810810_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810811_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810812_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810813_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810814_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810815_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810816_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810817_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810818_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810819_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810820_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810821_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810822_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810823_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810824_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810825_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810826_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810827_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810828_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810829_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810830_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810831_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810901_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810902_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810903_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810904_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810905_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810906_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810907_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810908_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810909_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810910_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810911_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810912_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810913_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810914_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810915_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810916_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810917_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810918_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810919_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810920_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810921_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810922_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810923_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810924_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810925_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810926_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810927_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810928_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810929_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19810930_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811001_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811002_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811003_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811004_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811005_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811006_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811007_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811008_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811009_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811010_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811011_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811012_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811013_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811014_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811015_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811016_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811017_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811018_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811019_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811020_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811021_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811022_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811023_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811024_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811025_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811026_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811027_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811028_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811029_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811030_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811031_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811101_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811102_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811103_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811104_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811105_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811106_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811107_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811108_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811109_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811110_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811111_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811112_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811113_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811114_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811115_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811116_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811117_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811118_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811119_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811120_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811121_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811122_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811123_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811124_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811125_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811126_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811127_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811128_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811129_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811130_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811201_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811202_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811203_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811204_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811205_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811206_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811207_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811208_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811209_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811210_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811211_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811212_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811213_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811214_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811215_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811216_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811217_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811218_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811219_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811220_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811221_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811222_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811223_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811224_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811225_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811226_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811227_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811228_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811229_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19811230_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19811231_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19820606_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19840526_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19850223_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19850606_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19851025_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19861105_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19870627_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19880324_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19881025_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19900910_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19910829_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19920221_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19930319_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19930908_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19940605_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19950322_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19950418_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19960115_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei                98        19960319_T.dbf
100%        Neue Datei               117        19970625_T.dbf

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

           Insgesamt   KopiertÜbersprungenKeine Übereinstimmung    FEHLER    Extras
Verzeich.:         1         0         1         0         0         0
  Dateien:       385       385         0         0         0         0
    Bytes:    41.5 k    41.5 k         0         0         0         0
   Zeiten:   0:00:01   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:01


Geschwindigkeit:               73753 Bytes/Sek.
Geschwindigkeit:               4.220 Megabytes/Min.

  Beendet: Thu Nov 27 13:04:03 2014

D:\>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like there should be anything wrong with your commands. Are these the exact commands, or are your paths different? Maybe with spaces in them? If spaces, ensure you enclose the complete path in quotes e.g. "d:\sorted results\1981"

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The paths are different, but none of mine have spaces in them. Just for fun I used the exact same paths as above and it's still the same faulty result. There are 20 files more in the 1981 folder. So it's a bug or what?

Comment: try with `dir /b /x` to see their short names..?

Comment: npocmaka, it lists the current directory. What does it help? What short names? I know the names of the directories...

Comment: Ooh.`dir /b /x` does not shows the short names.But `dir /x` will do it.All files under windows have two names -the second one is with 8.3 notation and replaces some characters with numbers.

Comment: Ok, I can now see a cryptic second name (including hexadecimal characters) for every file. But how does it help me copying the files? Some of the second names have the term 1981 in them, others not. So robocopy is not taking the second names to identify the files to be copied.

Comment: Please post robocopy's output.

Comment: For future reference, you can disable short names and/or remove them from existing files using the [`fsutil 8dot3name` command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621566.aspx).  This can save you a surprising amount of trouble.  (However, I don't recommend doing this on the C drive, since both Windows and third-party applications may be depending on short names there.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this to see if it works with the data you have.
It is unlikely to match a short filename I think.

```
@echo off
for /L %%a in (1981,1,1999) do robocopy "d:\files" "d:\results\%%a" "%%a????_T.dbf"
```

This should copy folders in the same way:

```
@echo off
for /L %%a in (1981,1,1999) do (
  for /d %%b in ("d:\files\%%a*") do echo/%%~nxb|findstr "^%%a">nul && robocopy "%%b" "d:\results\%%a\%%~nxb" /s
)
pause
```

Extra switches are required for hidden/system files etc.

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you very much for your help. Still wondering why it didn't work the other way though. Would the above command also work with folders?

Comment: The scenario with the folders would need to be explained.  As it is written it just looks for files in the `d:\files` folder.

Comment: In another case I have a folder full of folders with the same names like 19810101, 19810102 ... that also need to be copied in folders 1981, 1982 etc. It's basically the same as above only it's not files, but folders this time. I tried this before, but I've read somewhere that copying folders with wildcards in the name is not possible with robocopy and the likes. So after your one-line-solution I thought maybe it's possible after all.

Comment: It basically worked out, thank you! But now the same effect as in my original post appears again: I had folders for the years 1981, 1982 and 1991 in my main folder and robocopy copied them in the folders 1981, 1982, 1991 in the destination folder accordingly. Additionally he copied more folders from other years into the 1981, 1982.. folders in the destination folder. Plus he creates folders 1983, 1984, ... 1999 and puts folders from 1981, 1982 and 1991 in there (around 2-6 in each). Very strange behavior? Any ideas?

Comment: Test the folder copying batch file above, which has been edited.  Use a new destination folder.

Comment: Damn, you're a genius! That did it. All folders have been copied to the right folder. If I could only figure that code out. Guess I have to look into these commands/options to adapt it for future work. The thread can be closed I think, all my questions are answered.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it works. What it does is to try and match folder with the right year, but remember that it does match the short and long filename and the short filename can be unrelated to the actual term.  The echo command passes the detected folder name to findstr and filters on  a name that actually starts with the year (^ means to match the start of the line).  The `&&` operator only runs the robocopy command when the correct year is detected at the start of the folder name, by checking the errorlevel from findstr.